# Magento2 : Unable to serialize value while importing product description from CSV for configurable products

Tags: magento2, import, import-products

Hi, I was trying to add description to products using CSV file for configurable products but when I tried to import the CSV i got the error regarding Unable to serialize value but if I tried to import product one by one then the error don't pops up.

I have added description to the simple products only according to their store code wise and else description remains blank.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due The store views code that I have added in my CSV files are in wrong order or doesn't match with the store view codes presented. Please try exporting the file and reimporing that file as it as changing the material that worked for me.